# Is there any way to add CMS to Nextjs website (such as Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, seo, content-management-system, client-side

I developed a website using Nextjs (Client side only, and used Nextjs for the SEO).
I wanted to ask if there is a way to convert this website somehow from Nextjs to Wordpress or anything else, or even somehow connect it to CMS application, so my client can modify images and content any time he want by his own.

Currently, the web application in Nextjs is pretty static, all the pages and conntent are hard coded wroten.
All my data are in JSON files and such are the images in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is a pretty hot topic right now, and there are many ways to accomplish it.

Here are the general guidelines:

1. Set up a "headless CMS" - this can be WordPress (set up in a special way so you are using just the backend) - or there are many other popular options, such as Contentful, Sanity, Prismic...
2. Your CMS needs to have an API for Next.js to use.  If you go with WordPress, you can use the built-in REST API - or you can use the [WP GraphQL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-graphql)

This is such a popular topic, that if you search around, you'll find many helpful guides that go into more detail.  You'll want to search "Next.JS with WordPress headless CMS"

[Here's one example I found that uses GraphQL and looks fairly thorough.](https://dev.to/kendalmintcode/configuring-wordpress-as-a-headless-cms-with-next-js-3p1o)

Or, if you're not set on WordPress, check out Next.js-specific information for other popular headless CMS's - most of them will have specific documentation and guides for Next.JS - for example [Sanity's Next.JS Guides](https://www.sanity.io/exchange/type=guides/framework=nextjs).

WordPress is solid and flexible - but if you're not already a fairly strong WP developer, then I might recommend going with one of the more pre-packaged options (like Sanity, Prismic, Contentful, etc.) - many of them have a free tier.

Comment: Does this also allow to add pages dynamicaly? Change pages structure (Such as add h1, paragraphs and images)? Or only change content like hard coded JSON's?

Comment: It will allow managing page structure and content - adding and modifying - but you will have to build out the integration to do so.  Basically, it will allow for whatever you are willing and able to build into the integration with your Node.js logic.

Comment: Also adding and modify images ?

Comment: Yep! Might take a bit of extra work, but definitely possible